# ng-repeat active class with different style

Tags: angularjs, frontend

I am creating a list of offers with ng-repeat. Depending of each offer status, they should have different colors and, when active, it should have a different specific status as well. The active logic works well, but what is happening now, is that they all render as true, so they're all the same color. Feel free if you have any other ideas of doing this.

This is what I see when I inspect, after it renders:

```
 ng-class="{'offer card-active-false card row text-left': currentOfferId === offer.id, 'offer card card-false row text-left': currentOfferId !== offer.id}" class="offer card card-true row text-left"
```

Here is what I have on HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="offer in $parent.offersList track by $index">
  <button ng-click="$ctrl.setCurrentOffer(offer)">
    <div ng-if="" ng-class="{'offer card-active-{{offer.status}} card row text-left': currentOfferId === offer.id, 'offer card card-{{offer.status}} row text-left': currentOfferId !== offer.id}">
    //then I have my divs
    </div>
  </button>
</div>
```

CCS:

```
                .card-true {
                    background-color: #00FF44;
                }

                .card-false {
                    background-color: #C4C4CC;
                }

                .card- {
                  background-color: yellow;
                }

                .card-active-true {
                    background-color: #fff!important;
                    border-color: #00FF44;
                }

                .card-active-false {
                    background-color: #fff!important;
                    border-color: gray;
                }

                .card-active- {
                    background-color: #fff!important;
                    border-color: yellow;
                }
```

thanks!

Comment: Is the `ng-if` needed?

Comment: no. I removed but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put classes that always need to be present in a normal `class` attribute.

Then simplify the classes you need and separate them so you don't have to over-complicate the logic. My suggestions may be off, but it should look something like this:

- `card-status-...` - driven by `offer.status`
- `card-active` - driven by `currentOfferId === offer.id'

Then you could easily put the logic in `ngClass`, which lets you specify an array whose members can be strings that represent class names or objects whose keys are class names and whose boolean values indicate whether the class should be included. Like so:

```
<div class="offer card row text-left" 
    ng-class="[
        'card-status-' + offer.status,
        {'card-active' : currentOfferId === offer.id}
    ]">
```

Now in your CSS you can set up those classes by combining selectors:

```
.card {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.card-status-true {
    background-color: #00FF44;
}

.card-status-false {
    background-color: #C4C4CC;
}

.card.card-active {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-color: yellow;
}

.card.card-active.card-status-true {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-color: #00FF44;
}

.card.card-active.card-status-false {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    border-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Genius! <3
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, remove the complicated logic, which is obviously not binding properly inside the `ng-class`, it will only confuse and its not worth the time.

Note: I have used `$scope` variables instead of `this`, please use the GIST of the JSFiddle I'm sharing and try to build your code, I am unsure of the color requirements, please check and tell me if the code resolves your issue.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

**CODE:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.offersList = [{id:1, status: false}, {id:2, status: false}, {id:3, status: false}, {id:4, status: false}];
    $scope.currentOfferId = 0;
  $scope.setCurrentOffer=function(index){
    $scope.currentOfferId = $scope.offersList[index].id;
    $scope.offersList[index].status = !$scope.offersList[index].status;
  }
  $scope.filterClass = function(offer){
    var bool = offer.status ? 'true' : 'false';
    if($scope.currentOfferId === offer.id){
        return 'offer card-active-'+bool;
      }else{
        return 'offer card card-'+bool;
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear which classes you want applied to which situation. You need to hand ng-class an array with each separate condition, this was probably the root of your problem.
You can also use ternary for this (angular v.1.1.4+ introduced support for ternary operator) which makes things look a little neater:

```
<div ng-class="[offer.id ===currentOfferId ? 'card-active-true' : 'card-active-false', 
offer.status ? 'card-active-true' : 'card-false' ]"
class="offer card row text-left" >
```